# How to Be Censored Bad Words / Offensive Words in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

i'm developing an Android Social app in Android Studio

Can anyone know How to filter bad words / offensive words when posting a new status.

For Example i post something bad words and offensive it will turn to like this **"****"** also when i post many words it will turn like this **"i will hit your ***** right now"**

please if you know how to i really need it
Thank you in Advance.

This is my **PublishingActivity.java** Code

```
import android.content.DialogInterface; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager; 
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; 
import android.text.TextUtils; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.ImageButton; 
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.LinearLayout; 
import android.widget.TextView; 

import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.R; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.api.APIService; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.api.GlobalAPI; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.api.PostsAPI; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.api.UsersAPI; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.app.AppConst; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.data.LocationModel; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.data.ResponseModel; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.data.userItem; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.helpers.CacheManager; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.helpers.CropSquareTransformation; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.helpers.FilePath; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.helpers.GPSHelper; 
import com.iscooldev.socialnetwork.helpers.M; 
import com.google.gson.Gson; 
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken; 
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso; 
import com.thin.downloadmanager.DownloadRequest; 
import com.thin.downloadmanager.ThinDownloadManager; 

import java.io.File; 

import retrofit.Callback; 
import retrofit.RetrofitError; 
import retrofit.client.Response; 
import retrofit.mime.TypedFile; 

public class PublishActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { 
    public Intent mIntent; 
    public LinearLayoutManager layoutManager; 
    EditText insertedLink; 
    private ImageView mImagePreview; 
    private ImageButton addPhoto; 
    private ImageButton sendStatus; 
    private ImageButton changePrivacy; 
    private EditText statusInput; 
    private TextView profileName, postPrivacy; 
    private ImageView profilePicture; 
    private String privacy = "public"; 
    private String statusValue = null; 
    private String linkValue = null; 
    private Uri imageUriValue = null; 
    private LinearLayout urlPreviewLayout; 
    private TextView urlValuePreview; 
    private TextView placeValuePreview; 
    private LinearLayout placePreviewLayout; 
    private String placeValue = null; 
    private ThinDownloadManager downloadManager; 
    private CacheManager mCacheManager; 
    private Gson mGson; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        if (M.getToken(this) == null) { 
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class); 
            startActivity(mIntent); 
            finish(); 

        } else { 
            mCacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance(this); 
            mGson = new Gson(); 
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_publish); 
            initializeView(); 
            if (getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT)) { 
                setStatusValue(getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT).toString()); 
            } 
            if (getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) { 
                String text = getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT).toString(); 
                if (M.isValidUrl(text)) { 
                    setLinkValue(text); 
                } else { 
                    setStatusValue(text); 
                } 
            } 
            if (getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) { 
                setImageUriValue((Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)); 
                M.L(getIntent().getType()); 
            } 
            getUser(); 
        } 

    } 

    public void initializeView() { 
        downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager(AppConst.DOWNLOAD_THREAD_POOL_SIZE); 
        addPhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addPhoto); 
        sendStatus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendStatus); 
        changePrivacy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changePrivacy); 
        mImagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePreview); 
        statusInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statusEdittext); 
        profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.postOwnerImage); 
        profileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postOwnerName); 
        postPrivacy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postPrivacy); 
        TextView removeLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.removeLink); 
        TextView removePlace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.removePlace); 
        ImageButton addPlace = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addPlace); 
        ImageButton addLink = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addLink); 

        placePreviewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.placePreviewLayout); 
        placeValuePreview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeValuePreview); 

        urlPreviewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.urlPreviewLayout); 
        urlValuePreview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urlValuePreview); 

        sendStatus.setOnClickListener(this); 
        addPhoto.setOnClickListener(this); 
        changePrivacy.setOnClickListener(this); 
        addPlace.setOnClickListener(this); 
        addLink.setOnClickListener(this); 
        removePlace.setOnClickListener(this); 
        removeLink.setOnClickListener(this); 
        //including toolbar  and enabling the home button 
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar); 
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_publish)); 
    } 

    private void getUser() { 
        if (M.isNetworkAvailable(this)) { 

            UsersAPI mUsersAPI = APIService.createService(UsersAPI.class, M.getToken(this)); 
            mUsersAPI.getUser(0, new Callback<userItem>() { 
                @Override 
                public void success(userItem user, retrofit.client.Response response) { 
                    try { 
                        mCacheManager.write(mGson.toJson(user), "Profile-0.json"); 
                        updateView(user); 
                    } catch (Exception e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 
                } 

                @Override 
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) { 

                } 
            }); 
        } else { 
            try { 
                updateView((userItem) mGson.fromJson(mCacheManager.readString("Profile-0.json"), new TypeToken<userItem>() { 
                }.getType())); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    private void updateView(userItem user) { 
        if (user.getName() != null) { 
            profileName.setText(user.getName()); 
        } else { 
            profileName.setText(user.getUsername()); 
        } 
        if (getFilePath(user.getPicture()) != null) { 
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()) 
                    .load(getFilePath(user.getPicture())) 
                    .transform(new CropSquareTransformation()) 
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_holder) 
                    .error(R.drawable.image_holder) 
                    .into(profilePicture); 
        } else { 
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()) 
                    .load(AppConst.IMAGE_PROFILE_URL + user.getPicture()) 
                    .transform(new CropSquareTransformation()) 
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_holder) 
                    .error(R.drawable.image_holder) 
                    .into(profilePicture); 
            downloadFile(AppConst.IMAGE_PROFILE_URL + user.getPicture(), user.getPicture()); 

        } 
    } 

    private void downloadFile(String url, String hash) { 
        if (getFilePath(hash) == null) { 
            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url); 
            Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(M.getFilePath(getApplicationContext(), hash)); 
            DownloadRequest downloadRequest = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri) 
                    .setDestinationURI(destinationUri); 
            downloadManager.add(downloadRequest); 
        } 
    } 

    private String getFilePath(String hash) { 
        return M.filePath(getApplicationContext(), hash); 
    } 

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
            if (requestCode == AppConst.SELECT_PICTURE) { 
                setImageUriValue(data.getData()); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(final View v) { 
        if (v.getId() == R.id.removePlace) { 
            setPlaceValue(null); 
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.removeLink) { 
            setLinkValue(null); 
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.addPlace) { 
            final GPSHelper mGpsHelper = new GPSHelper(this); 
            if (mGpsHelper.canGetLocation()) { 
                GlobalAPI mGlobalAPI = APIService.createService(GlobalAPI.class, M.getToken(this)); 
                mGlobalAPI.getCurrentPlace(mGpsHelper.getLatitude(), mGpsHelper.getLongitude(), new Callback<LocationModel>() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void success(LocationModel location, retrofit.client.Response response) { 
                        if (location.isStatus()) { 
                            setPlaceValue(location.getAddress()); 
                        } else { 
                            mGpsHelper.showSettingsAlert(); 
                        } 
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) { 
                        mGpsHelper.showSettingsAlert(); 
                    } 
                }); 
            } else { 
                mGpsHelper.showSettingsAlert(); 
            } 
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.addLink) { 
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

            alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.Insert_a_link)); 

            insertedLink = new EditText(this); 
            insertedLink.setText("http://"); 
            alert.setView(insertedLink); 
            alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), this); 
            alert.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), this); 
            alert.show(); 
        } else if (v.getId() == addPhoto.getId()) { 
            launchImageChooser(); 
        } else if (v.getId() == sendStatus.getId()) { 

            String statusText = statusInput.getText().toString().trim(); 
            if (!statusText.isEmpty()) { 
                setStatusValue(statusText); 
            } 
            if (getStatusValue() == null && getImageUriValue() == null && getLinkValue() == null) { 
                M.T(v, 
                        getString(R.string.Error_empty_post)); 
            } else { 
                PostsAPI mPostsAPI = APIService.createService(PostsAPI.class, M.getToken(this)); 

                TypedFile image = null; 
                if (getImageUriValue() != null) { 
                    image = new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(FilePath.getPath(this, getImageUriValue()))); 
                } 
                M.showLoadingDialog(this); 
                mPostsAPI.publishPost(image, getStatusValue(), getLinkValue(), getPlaceValue(), privacy, new Callback<ResponseModel>() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void success(ResponseModel responseModel, Response response) { 
                        M.hideLoadingDialog(); 
                        M.T(v, responseModel.getMessage()); 
                        if (responseModel.isDone()) { 
                            startActivity(new Intent(PublishActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); 
                            finish(); 
                        } 
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) { 
                        M.hideLoadingDialog(); 
                        M.T(v, getString(R.string.ServerError)); 
                    } 
                }); 
            } 
        } else if (v.getId() == changePrivacy.getId()) { 
            if (privacy.equals("public")) { 
                postPrivacy.setText(R.string.privatePrivacy); 
                privacy = "private"; 
                M.T(v, getString(R.string.changed_to_private)); 
            } else { 
                postPrivacy.setText(R.string.publicPrivacy); 
                privacy = "public"; 
                M.T(v, getString(R.string.changed_to_public)); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    private void launchImageChooser() { 

        Intent intent = new Intent(); 
        intent.setType("image/*"); 
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
        startActivityForResult( 
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose An Image"), 
                AppConst.SELECT_PICTURE); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        String Link = insertedLink.getText().toString(); 
        if (!Link.equals("http://") && !Link.equals("")) { 
            setLinkValue(Link); 
        } 
    } 

    public String getPlaceValue() { 
        return placeValue; 
    } 

    public void setPlaceValue(String placeValue) { 
        if (placeValue != null) { 

            if (placePreviewLayout.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) { 
                placePreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                placeValuePreview.setText(placeValue); 
            } 
        } else { 
            if (placePreviewLayout.getVisibility() != View.GONE) { 
                placePreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                placeValuePreview.setText(""); 
            } 
        } 
        this.placeValue = placeValue; 
    } 

    public Uri getImageUriValue() { 
        return imageUriValue; 
    } 

    public void setImageUriValue(Uri imageUriValue) { 
        this.imageUriValue = imageUriValue; 
        mImagePreview.setImageURI(imageUriValue); 
        if (mImagePreview.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) { 
            mImagePreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        } 
    } 

    public String getLinkValue() { 
        return linkValue; 
    } 

    public void setLinkValue(String linkValue) { 
        if (linkValue != null) { 

            if (urlPreviewLayout.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) { 
                urlPreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                urlValuePreview.setText(linkValue); 
            } 
        } else { 
            if (urlPreviewLayout.getVisibility() != View.GONE) { 
                urlPreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                urlValuePreview.setText(""); 
            } 
        } 
        this.linkValue = linkValue; 
    } 

    public String getStatusValue() { 
        return statusValue; 
    } 

    public void setStatusValue(String statusValue) { 
        String statusInputValue = statusInput.getText().toString().trim(); 
        if (!statusValue.equals(statusInputValue)) { 
            String finalStatus; 
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(statusInputValue)) { 
                finalStatus = statusValue; 
            } else { 
                finalStatus = statusInputValue + " " + statusValue; 
            } 
            statusInput.setText(finalStatus); 
            this.statusValue = finalStatus; 
        } else { 
            this.statusValue = statusValue; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have an input string `s` and the list of words you want to replace by asterisks:

```
String s = "i will hit your head right now";
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("head", "now"); // suppose these words are offensive
```

You just iterate over list of offensive words, looking if input string contains one, and perform a replacement. The simplest way to do this is by using regex:

```
for (String word : words) {
     Pattern rx = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     s = rx.matcher(s).replaceAll(new String(new char[word.length()]).replace('\0', '*'));
}

// s: i will hit your **** right ***
```

I've added `\\b` at the front and end of regex pattern to match just whole words (i. e. "head" will be processed, "header" will not). And this piece:

```
new String(new char[n]).replace('\0', c)
```

constructs a new string of `n` chars `c`.

After that, use resulting `s` wherever you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Sasha i will try this :D

Comment: im so sorry can you tell me where i put in the line of my code?
please :(

Comment: @KarlGötze i believe it should be something like `public void setStatusValue(String statusValue) { statusValue = removeBadWords(statusValue); /*...*/ }`

Comment: thank you for helping me, im so sorry i still not get the right code of my app how it works, i know that your code it works for my app but i dont know what to do, can you please help me with this ? you're the only way to help me fix my problems.

Thankyou

Comment: @ShashaSalauyou can you help me to arrange the code where to put it? I'm confused I did all possible statements but it didn't work :(

Comment: find a place where post is displayed, and apply this filter to input string

Comment: Thank you @ShashaSalauyou i got it now :D

Comment: from the code I think it won't detect the first word of the sentence because the format only "word + "\\b"" ? I haven't tried it though

Comment: @Kyk You should try. `\b` is a zero-width assertion matching "alphanumeric word" boundary regardless of its position

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic about java, not android related. A way to do this is you make a list of your bad words and replace it from the string that user input. Refer to example below

```
        String userInput = "this is an example of some bad words";
        ArrayList<String> badWords = new ArrayList<>();
        badWords.add("some");
        badWords.add("bad");
        badWords.add("words");
        for (int i = 0; i < badWords.size(); i++) {
            String badWord = badWords.get(i);
            if(userInput.toLowerCase().contains(badWord)){
                userInput = userInput.replace(badWord, "*****");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code will also replace words inside other words, (e. g. `awesome -> awe*****`) and it doesn't take into account length of replaced words (5 *s every time)

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yea, i'm aware of that, it's just another simple example :)